# How to fix Windows 10 windows store app icons?

Tags: windows-10

How do I fix my Windows Store app icons on Windows 10 when doing a search? Example:

[image]

However, in the app list it displays fine:

[image]

As you can see, it displays the image icon instead. I have followed instructions on resetting the icon cache but that hasn't helped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was settings being synced between machines via my Microsoft account.

I tried all sorts of fixes, including repairing Windows Store Apps, SFC, clearing icon and thumbnail cache files, etc. I tried switching the *System > Advanced System Settings > Performance > Settings > Show thumbnails instead of icons*. I tried *Explorer > File > Change folder and search options > View > Always show icons, never thumbnails*. I tried disabling the syncing of *Other Windows settings* under *Settings > Accounts > Sync your settings*.

The only way I was able to fix the issue was:

1. Turn of settings syncing with your Microsoft account on all Windows installs. (*Settings > Accounts > Sync your settings*)
2. Go to https://onedrive.live.com/win8personalsettingsprivacy and click the *Remove* button to delete the cloud copy of all settings
3. Convert your Window account to a local user account, thereby unlinking it from your Microsoft account (*Settings > Accounts* click the *Sign in with a local account instead* link)
4. Create a new Windows account on the machine, first as a local-only account so you can pick your username (*Settings > Accounts > Family &   other people* then *Add someone else to this PC*).
5. Log into the new account and go to *Settings > Accounts* to link it up to your Microsoft account
6. Move settings and files from your old local account to the new account
7. Remove your old local account

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.